# Aerospike installation completed incorrect

Tags: aerospike

I want uninstalled and installed again aerospike, but after installation it cannot start, because of there is no aerospike.conf file. What should I do now

Comment: What install pacakge are you using? .dep, .rpm? check out this link: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-remove-and-clean-up-an-aerospike-server-installation/4839

Comment: @Ivolmar I am using ubuntu 18.04 installation through the terminal. I have done this steps in order to remove aerospike.

Comment: was aerospike.conf deleted manually? You could try to remove and purge again and re-install. (apt-get purge packagename or apt-get remove --purge packagename)